# How do you respond immediately from an Azure Function PowerShell HTTP Trigger and then respond "out of band to another Url"?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-functions

I have a PowerShell HTTP trigger wired up to a Slack command. If the PS trigger responds in < 3 seconds all is good. I've got this working

If it takes longer, Slack requires two things, respond immediately and then respond out of band on the `response_url`.

This works. If I put a `sleep 10` after the `set-content`, neither return and Slack says it timed out.

Is there way to accomplish this in PowerShell?

```
@"
{
  "response_type": "ephemeral",
   "text": "Checking $(get-date) ..."
}
"@ |  set-content $res -Encoding Ascii
```

The out of band works.

```
$b = @"
{
    "response_type": "in_channel",
    "text": "It's 80 degrees right now.",
    "attachments": [
        {
            "text":"Partly cloudy today and tomorrow"
        }
    ]
}
"@

Invoke-RestMethod $responseUrl -Method post -Body $b -ContentType "application/json"
```

Comment: The "easy" way would be to always return the immediate response and then do it out of band, even when it would have completed in under 3 seconds. Otherwise you'll need to background whatever it is you're doing and time it so that after 2 - 2.5 seconds you can return the immediate response. That's doable if you can runspaces in an Azure function (invoked asynchronously), and and a wait that can time out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right pattern of doing that in Azure Functions is to have your HTTP trigger function just push a message in a queue, then return immediately. Then have another Azure Function that's listening on that queue and then run your logic there.